# While loop for beginning craps program is not executing properly.

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am trying to build a craps program that will prompt the user if they would like to continue to play after they win or loose. If yes is selected then it will go through the loop again. If no is selected then it will display the number of wins and loses. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I think I have been looking at it for a while and am at the point where I may just be my own enemy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include  <Windows.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
char answer(0);
int wins(0), loses(0);

while (answer == 'y'); {
    srand(time(NULL));  // one time at the top of the program
    int d1(0), d2(0), d3(0), d4(0), roll(0), roll2(0), point(0);

    d1 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
    d2 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
    roll = d1 + d2;
    point = d1 + d2;

    cout << "Player Rolled " << d1 << "+" << d2 << "=" << roll << endl;
    cout << "Point is:" << point << endl;

    if (roll == 7 || roll == 11)
    {
        cout << "Player Rolled " << d1 << "+" << d2 << "=" << roll << endl << "Player Wins" << endl;
        wins++;
        Sleep(2000);  // 2 second pause
        cout << "Do you want to play again? (Y or N)";
        cin >> answer;

    }
    else if (roll == 2 || roll == 3 || roll == 12)
    {

        cout << "Player Rolled " << d1 << "+" << d2 << "=" << roll << endl << "Player loses" << endl;
        loses++;
        Sleep(2000);  // 2 second pause
        cout << "Do you want to play again? (Y or N)";
        cin >> answer;

    }
    else
    {

        do
        {
            d3 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
            d4 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
            roll2 = d3 + d4;

            if (roll2 == roll)
            {
                cout << "Player Rolled " << d3 << "+" << d4 << "=" << roll2 << endl << "Player Wins" << endl;
                wins++;
                Sleep(2000);  // 2 second pause
                cout << "Do you want to play again? (Y or N)";
                cin >> answer;
            }

        } while (roll2 != 7);
        cout << "Player Rolled " << d3 << "+" << d4 << "=" << roll2 << endl << "Player loses" << endl;
        loses++;
        Sleep(2000);  // 2 second pause
        cout << "Do you want to play again? (Y or N)";
        cin >> answer;
    }
 } 

cout << wins << " Wins and " << loses << " Loses" << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code reduced to an SSCCE: (see http://sscce.org)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char answer(0);

    while (answer == 'y') {
        cout << "running\n";
    }
    cout << "end\n";
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/rsPVP9

All this does is print `end` because answer is never set to 'y'.

To make this run even once you should initialize `answer` with `'y'` instead of `(0)`:

```
char answer('y');
```

Or use a `do ... while (answer == 'y');` loop.

Your remark about being your own enemy: that's when it is time to boil your problem down to something simpler so you can find the stone in your shoe, as I did here with the SSCCE version of your code.